# Getting error 500 for passing a list of string in post request to jersey app

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I developed a jersey app with grizzly server which has a rest endpoint which looks like below.

```
@Path("/testPost")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response testPost(UserGroupDto ugdto)
{

    System.out.println("inside testpost");
    return Response.accepted(ugdto).build();  
}
```

My UserGroupdto looks like below

```
public class UserGroupDto {

    private String groupId;
    private List<String> listOfUserId;

    public UserGroupDto() {
        super();
    }

    public UserGroupDto(String groupId, List<String> listOfUserId) {
        super();
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.listOfUserId = listOfUserId;
    }
}
```

I am using POSTMAN as client and sending below json request

```
{

    "groupId": "G004",
    "listOfUserId" :[
        "f3457g",
        "5f3rdt",
        "U105"
    ]
}
```

I am using below dependencies for json in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
<artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
<version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting an Internal Server Error 500. No error coming on the console and not printing the sysout statement. It seems to be working with other kind of Dto object where List is not involved. Please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When I tested your service and request in my local environment, it worked perfectly fine, as it didn't produces 500 exception for me. You should also post your exception stacktrace here.

Also in response it was giving me blank object, because you don't have setters and getters in your model class.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest to remove that

```
super()
```

call inside constructors. Yous object doesn't extend other objects so, implicitly, it extends the Java `Object` class. Therefore you are calling `Object` constructor, an operation which is already perfomed by the compiler.

To solve your problem try adding `set` and `get` to your class. `groupId` and `listOfUserId` are private then they couldn't be set from outside your class.

I didn't test it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. I have getters and setters present in my class. I just dint post them here as it's normal to have them in pojo class. I will remove super() from my default constructor and also will have a look at the postman body type. Let me know if u feel the problem could occur due to some other reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure while using postman in the body you are selecting raw type and application/json. I executed your code and I am getting no problem. May be if you share the logs being generated I can help you.